# what happens to data when insert overwrite table killed

Tags: hive

I have below queries running on hive. but unfortunately  they got killed by someone what happens to data when I select the query.

case1: insert overwrite b select * from a;
case2: insert into b select * from a;

Question:if I run select * from b ; in above 2 cases  can I see the data ?

Answer (score 0):

Data will stay as before `insert-overwrite` query.
You can check TBLPROPERTIES ("auto.purge"="true") or not. For a managed table, previous data of the table is not moved to Trash when `INSERT OVERWRITE` query is run against the table.
insert overwrite will overwrite only when query succeeds and if process fails or killed, it should hold original table data.